# why cant we see who down/upvoted you?

Tags: feature-request

I would like to know why you dont have that option, as i belive someone is going around downvoting my answers that i know shouldnt be downvoted, surely you should have the option to see who downvoted you? Iv been down voted 4 times in two days where usually i dont get downvoted! what makes it worse is i know my answers that iv just been downvoted for i know are the correct way to go about it.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the reason the system was designed this way; so that you don't get to see who down-voted you; is because otherwise it would result in tit-for-tat down-voting and other retaliatory behaviour. This kind of thing damages the site by creating noise and wasting a lot of the moderators' time.

Of course I know that you would never do anything like that, but not all users have such restraint and stoic professionalism.

Comment: yes it does seem stupid that some users dont hold that restrains unfortunatly, It would of been a nice feature for you to see who upvoted and downvoted you. I think a downvote more than twice on the same user should be heavy on the user who downvoted, this way they would think twice before down vote without reading properly! or downvoting should be reviewed if under certin ammount of reputation. either way you are right and its annoying that people would behave like this!

Comment: it is a moot point to ask this kind of questions here, as we (SharePoint Meta) dont have any kind of influence on general site behaviour. Post on SO Meta, but as SPDoctor say, there are good reasons why you cannot see who up/downvoted you. If you have a suspicion on who it is, we as moderators can see who votes on who up/down, so if you feel somebody is going for the foot rather than the ball let us know. Be aware that downvoting actually costs reputation for the one downvoting.

Comment: LOL @ "stoic professionalism". @almostSharepointMaster what if a user is serial posting non-informative or incorrect answers? Surely you wouldn't want to be heavily penalized for downvoting multiple low-quality answers from the same low-quality source.

Comment: LOL i see your point ;)