# Accountability on downvotes?

Tags: discussion

Downvoting on questions and answers are an important part of the StackExchange network. It's there to show the communitys total voting. But to be able to ask better questions, and provide better answers, I would like to suggest a comment to be added to the downvote.

The down vote is someone who disagree with the post, and it would greatly help if a downvote was accompanied by a **-1** comment. This makes it easier for the poster to know which part of the question/answer the downvoter disagrees on. The poster may then edit the question/answer to make it more in line and maybe improve the post.

An upvote is different, since the voter agrees on the post, and no comment is therefore needed.

## Not forcing - Encouraging

Thanks to Daniel's answer, I need to clarify myself. the intention is not to force users to post a comment, just to encourage them to add a comment to give the poster feedback of what was downvoted on.

This has also been discussed on StackOverflow Meta in the post [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes).

Comment: If this is implemented on StackExchange, as it seems, what do we need to do to get this little friendly reminder here as well?

Comment: @RobertLindgren I'm not sure. Maybe if the community wants it we can request it at teachers lounge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree. Then we end up with the situation/concern raised in the post: [why cant we see who down/upvoted you?](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/a/767/2536)

By forcing users to leave a comment upon downvoting will then display who have downvoted you and some people may not take getting downvoted as light-hearted as others.

It would be super nice if everybody left a comment explaining their reason to downvote, yes. I just don't think forcing a comment out of a user when downvoting will achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: The intention is not to force a comment on a downvote. Just to encourage users who downvote a post to add a comment.

Comment: I agree with the comment along with the downvote. Atleast I will take that into practice now. Hopefully others will as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is another issue at hand. I have NO IDEA why I got -2 down vote on a correct answer. Is my answer wrong? Is my answer misleading? Can it be improved? I think you should be accountable for the down vote.

Or, is this a "community thing"? Should I just blow off the down vote and not worry about the why, if that's the attitude, then why have down votes at all?